# Uncaught TypeError: soliloquy_14.soliloquy is not a function

Tags: jquery

I have a problem width Soliloquy and I don't know how to fix this:

> Uncaught TypeError: soliloquy_14.soliloquy is not a function
>           at (index):574
>           at dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
>           at r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)

I changed the jQuery version a few times, and it didn't help.

Comment: Possibly better place to ask: https://soliloquywp.com/contact/

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, if you have any other slider, you must turn it off.